# Powershell Property count

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to take the count of property based on the result,

Example :

```
get-service | select displayname,status
```

I need the count of status based on status name, something like below

```
Stopped = 30
Running = 50
StartPending = 2
```

Please help me on this

Comment: `group status -NoElement`

Comment: @PetSerAl Post an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Group-Object` cmdlet to group objects by some property. If you only need a count and does not need objects themselves, then you can use `-NoElement` switch.

```
Get-Service | Group-Object Status -NoElement
```